# How can I cut the tiles outside of the cabinet?

Tags: tile, ceramic-tile

I want to replace the tiles in my kitchen but I don't want to redo all the cabinets.

Some tiles are partially underneath the cabinets, so I suppose I need to cut the portion exposed outside of the cabinets before peeling them off.

I am not even sure what's the materials of my "tiles"... they don't look like real tiles. They are kind of soft and appear to stick onto the floor.

Are there such tools?

Comment: Glue on tiles are usually vinyl or other such material.  YOu should be able to cut them with a sharp utility knife.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just cut the tile off at the edge of the cabinet toe board and along cabinet ends. Particularly for vinyl tile as others have suggested. However keep in mind that when you come with new flooring that simply butts up to the edge of the cabinet toe board and along the ends of the cabinets you may then have to add some additional molding over the edge of the new flooring.

This molding would be necessary to hold down the edge of new flooring (particularly important if you are coming with new tile or single sheet vinyl) and it will cover the edge seam for aesthetics.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have vinyl floor.

It all depends on what floor you putting down after. 
If your putting down a floating timber floor of some kind you can lay that on top. 
Otherwise you would need to remove it. 
Run a Stanley knife along side the kicker (cupboards) then you should be able to pull them up.

If you post a picture of the floor can probably tell better what type of floor it is.